# How to insert xml data in to a table?

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

I have below XML File.

```
<steps>
  <step debug="Checking dialed number" Seq="63" dbtime="0" calltime="05/01/2014 20:00:49" />
  <step name="Playing welcome" Seq="2" Language="spanish" calltime="05/01/2014 20:00:50" />
  <step debug="Message played" Seq="64" playtime="31" calltime="05/01/2014 20:00:50" />
  <step debug="Check message" Seq="63" dbtime="0" calltime="05/01/2014 20:00:50" />
  <step name="Prompting" Seq="3" calltime="05/01/2014 20:00:50" />
  <step debug="Message played" Seq="64" playtime="9158" calltime="05/01/2014 20:00:59" />
  <step debug="Input received" Seq="65" usertime="18486" calltime="05/01/2014 20:01:25" />
  <step name="User Input : 1" Seq="12" Input="1" calltime="05/01/2014 20:01:25" />
  <step debug="Validate ID" Seq="63" dbtime="203" calltime="05/01/2014 20:01:25" />
  <step debug="Check Multi" Seq="63" dbtime="16" calltime="05/01/2014 20:01:25" />
  <step name="Prompting for" Seq="20" calltime="05/01/2014 20:01:25" />
  <step debug="Message played" Seq="64" playtime="31" calltime="05/01/2014 20:01:25" />
  <step debug="Input received" Seq="65" usertime="3495" calltime="05/01/2014 20:01:29" />
  <step name="User Input : 61" Seq="21" DutyCode="61" calltime="05/01/2014 20:01:29" />
</steps>
```

Want to insert data columnwise in below table.

```
create table xmltest 
(    debug varchar(40), 
     name varchar(40), 
     lang varchar(15), 
     paytime int, 
     dutycode int,
     usertime int, 
     seq int, 
     dbtime int, 
     calltime datetime
);
```

Thanks

Comment: what have you tried if anything? you will get a better response if you show an attempt at a solution rather than asking for people to do all the work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
-- Assuming you have your XML in a SQL variable of type XML ....
DECLARE @Input XML = '<steps>
  <step debug="Checking dialed number" Seq="63" dbtime="0" calltime="05/01/2014 20:00:49" />
  <step name="Playing welcome" Seq="2" Language="spanish" calltime="05/01/2014 20:00:50" />
  <step debug="Message played" Seq="64" playtime="31" calltime="05/01/2014 20:00:50" />
  <step debug="Check message" Seq="63" dbtime="0" calltime="05/01/2014 20:00:50" />
  <step name="Prompting" Seq="3" calltime="05/01/2014 20:00:50" />
  <step debug="Message played" Seq="64" playtime="9158" calltime="05/01/2014 20:00:59" />
  <step debug="Input received" Seq="65" usertime="18486" calltime="05/01/2014 20:01:25" />
  <step name="User Input : 1" Seq="12" Input="1" calltime="05/01/2014 20:01:25" />
  <step debug="Validate ID" Seq="63" dbtime="203" calltime="05/01/2014 20:01:25" />
  <step debug="Check Multi" Seq="63" dbtime="16" calltime="05/01/2014 20:01:25" />
  <step name="Prompting for" Seq="20" calltime="05/01/2014 20:01:25" />
  <step debug="Message played" Seq="64" playtime="31" calltime="05/01/2014 20:01:25" />
  <step debug="Input received" Seq="65" usertime="3495" calltime="05/01/2014 20:01:29" />
  <step name="User Input : 61" Seq="21" DutyCode="61" calltime="05/01/2014 20:01:29" />
</steps>'

-- insert into the target table
INSERT INTO dbo.xmltest(debug, name, lang, paytime, dutycode, usertime, seq, dbtime, calltime)
  -- select from all <step> elements in the XML
  SELECT
    debug = xc.value('@debug', 'varchar(40)'),
    name = xc.value('@name', 'varchar(40)'),
    lang = xc.value('@Language', 'varchar(15)'),
    paytime = xc.value('@playtime', 'int'),
    dutycode = xc.value('@DutyCode', 'int'),
    usertime = xc.value('@usertime', 'int'),
    seq = xc.value('@Seq', 'int'),
    dbtime = xc.value('@dbtime', 'int'),
    calltime = xc.value('@calltime', 'DateTime')
FROM
    @Input.nodes('/steps/step') AS XT(XC)
```